# trying to use simplexml to access the name from ean hotel list

Tags: javascript, php, simplexml

I am trying to use simplexml to access the hotelname from an api, showing a hotel list.

I have used this code so far. It seems right to me, but I still can't get it to work.

```
<?php

  $xml_file = 'http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=99&apiKey=ycdydfqdz4w5huxv4psfxs8h&cid=55505&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&countryCode=US&city=Dallas&stateProvinceCode=TX&searchRadius=50&numberOfResults=20&arrivalDate=08/31/2014&departureDate=09/15/2014&minRate=100&maxRate=1000&room1=1&numberOfAdults=2';
  $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

  $response = $xml->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary;
  foreach($response as $val){ 
    echo $val->name;
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be your new code:

```
<?php

  $xml_file = 'http://dev.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=99&apiKey=ycdydfqdz4w5huxv4psfxs8h&cid=55505&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&supplierCacheTolerance=MED_ENHANCED&countryCode=US&city=Dallas&stateProvinceCode=TX&searchRadius=50&numberOfResults=20&arrivalDate=08/31/2014&departureDate=09/15/2014&minRate=100&maxRate=1000&room1=1&numberOfAdults=2';
  $content = file_get_contents($xml_file);

  $xml = json_decode($content);
  //$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_file);

  $response = $xml->HotelListResponse->HotelList->HotelSummary;
  foreach($response as $val){ 
    echo $val->name;
  }

?>
```

Somehow the file request answers with a JSON file. Just parse it this way.

Comment: No, that was just a suggestion for the next time. You actually just need to use this line instead of yours: `$response = $xml->HotelList->HotelSummary;`.

Comment: What's your output, when you use `print_r($xml);` right after calling `simplexml_load_file`? Should be a pretty long output. You might have to save it to pastebin.com

Comment: Sorry my bad. Updated the answer